# Primefaces Dialog panel not support dynamic page

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 5.1 Dialog panel to include dynamic page.In every dynamic page i use panel.First it will work fine.When I press close button panel to  also hide dialog panel.Next I press link in button mainForm dialog show but dynamic page not include.I try below code:

**main.xhtml:**

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
........
<p:commandLink id="designationaddMoreId" action="#{User.addMoreButton}"
oncomplete="PF('addMoreModalPanel').show();"                                            
</h:form>

<p:dialog id="addMoreModalPanel" widgetVar="addMoreModalPanel" showHeader="false"  dynamic="true">
 <ui:include src="${user.dynamicPage}" 
 </p:dialog>
```

**Department.xhtml**

```
<h:form id="department">
  <p:panel id="departmentPanel" header="#{common.UserLabel}" closable="true">
    <p:ajax event="close"  process="@form" onstart="PF('addMoreModalPanel').hide()" />
..........
</p:panel>
....
</h:form>
```

In main form I use more than one link button and press link button to show modal panel and different pages include.
In include page (ex:departement.xhtml) close using ajax it's work fine.But I click another time department link department page not shown. in dilog panel it only show empty page upto when I refresh page.

Comment: You seem to not be rerendering anything.

Answer (score 0):

look at the EL Expression

```
<p:commandLink id="designationaddMoreId" action="#{User.addMoreButton}"
oncomplete="PF('addMoreModalPanel').show();"
```

your wrote

```
#{User.function}
```

and inside the dialog you use

```
src="${user.dynamicPage}"
```

i guess commandLink will throw a npe ? Take a look at the xml response when using ajax.

Comment: When First I click dialog panel page include work fine.When I close button  Department panel using ajax event close both dialog and current panel Close.But next time onwards to commandlink button not include page